# Kendo Grid with checkbox - how to detect rows with checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have the following kendo grid with a checkbox column:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.ParcelViewModel>()
  .Name("DetailedParcelGrid")
  .AutoBind(true)
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelKey)
           .ClientTemplate("<button type='button' class='btn btn-taxapp btn-primary assesment-taxyear-add' id='btnAddTaxYear'><b>Add Tax Year</b></button>")
           .Title("")
           .Width(200);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelKey)
            .ClientTemplate("<span class=\"assesment-parcel-edit glyphicon glyphicon-edit\" style=\"color: rgb(40, 96, 144)\"></span></a>")
            .Title("")
            .Width(30);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelKey).Hidden(true);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.LotNo).Title("Lot #").Width(50);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.AssembledTaxDescription).Title("Tax Description").Width(140);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.SchoolDistrict).Title("School District").Width(120);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelStreetNo).Title("Street Number").Width(110);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ItemNo).Title("Item").Width(50);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.Class).Width(50);
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelStatus).Title("Parcel Status").Width(120);
      columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' />").Title("Bulk Update").Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
      columns.Bound(parcel => parcel.ParcelNotes).Title("Parcel Notes");

  })
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(n => n.CaseKey))
        .Read(read => { read.Action("GetDetailedParcelDetails", "Parcel").Data("{ CaseKey: " + @Model.CaseKey + "}"); }))
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    )
```

There is a button on the page that, when it is clicked, causes a javascript function to run.  This is the code of the function:

```
var CaseKey = $('#CaseKey').val();
var saveInd = "N";
var obj = [];
var GridData = $("#BulkParcelStatusUpdateGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = GridData.dataSource.data();
var key = "";
var origStatus = "";
var newStatus = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    key = item.ParcelKey;
    origStatus = item.ParcelStatus;
    newStatus = $('#txtBulkUpdateValue').val();
    var oneRecord = {};
    oneRecord = {
        CaseKey: CaseKey,
        ParcelKey: key,
        ParcelStatus: newStatus
    }
    obj.push(oneRecord);
    saveInd = "Y";
    }
}
}
```

I only want to add an object into the array if the checkbox in the row is checked.  How can I find the checkbox in the item and how do I determine if its checked?

Thank you for any assistance.